# Concatenate two character vectors

Tags: r, shiny

I have these two character vectors as shown below -

```
x <- c("Beef/Pork", "Sugar sweeteened bev.","Total fruit")
y <- c("beefpork", "ssb", "total_fruit")
```

I want to create another vector based on this (like below). I need this to put it in `selectInput( )` in shiny.

```
choiceVec <- c("Beef/Pork" = "beefpork",
               "Sugar sweeteened bev." = "ssb",
               "Total fruit" = "total_fruit")
```

Comment: Use `paste()`, e.g. `paste(x, "=", y)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setNames`.

```
identical(setNames(y, x), choiceVec)
#[1] TRUE
```